# How may I set the page size using pagination with Tanstack table with solid.js?

Tags: solid-js

I'trying to addapt the example in the documentation of TanStaeck Table for Pagination using react

https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/pagination

to solid.js [i.e.: using solid-table]

However the following part for letting the user choose the page size does not work:

```
    <select
          value={table.getState().pagination.pageSize}
          onChange={e => {
            table.setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map(pageSize => (
            <option value={pageSize}>
              Mostrar {pageSize} filas
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

It seemes that there is a problem with the reactivity of the table.
The pagination state is updated, but the table is not re-draw in the DOM. (I known that unlike what happends in React, in Solid.js the render function is only run once)

Hence, I think that I would need somehow to add a signal connecting the PaginationState. Something like  the signals in the SortingState in the example

https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/solid/sorting

but nothing of what I have tried worked.

On the other hand, this code, for setting a button for advancing to the next page
does work:

```
        <button onClick={() => table.nextPage()}>Next Page</button>
```

Any idea that can help? Could it be a bug in solid-table?